# Would you suggest Google Analytic for tracking Users activities in your Web App Application Admin section?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, google-analytics

I'm developing a CMS for my website.

I need track Users activities in my Cms Admin section (protected by password).

I would like to know:

- If is possible add GA (Google Anlytic) code and use it even if the pages where the code is placed are covered by password.
- If such use can create security vulnerability of any kind. (If is good or bad practice).
- How to retrieve easily the statistics from pages in Admin section if the folder for admin is (example: ADMIN) in GA account. They come up like /admin/mypage.aspx??? Or how???

Generally, I would like your opinion about it and if you are using this approch it in your current web application.

Thanks for your time!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can put GA on any page - password protected or not.
- Security vulnerability depends on
  what you're sending to GA but in
  general, nothing that's sent is
  personal, etc.
- You can view the "Content" report and
  enter a filter at the bottom to show
  pages within "Admin." The full path of the page will show.

In summary, I don't see why not. GA does not care where the page resides in your site - it will work the same as it would for your public pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the purpose of GA. It is used to measure ROI by putting together data from visits, conversion rates etc and to identify KPIs of your site. I believe that you don't expect to have ROI just from the site administration.

I think that actions done by admins can be easily tracked from database, if the structure is well designed (ex when what was created, logs and so on)